# Nested Dictionaries and a String Indices Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Thanks for taking the time to help me.  I have the following code and can't figure out for the life of me why it isn't working.  Please forgive me, I have only been working with Python for the last 2 weeks or so, so I am sure I am messing up all over the place.

```
import os
import plistlib



pl = {1:{11:'k','Letters':'qrst',13:'m'},
      2:{11:'k','Letters':'lmn',13:'m'},
      3:'c',
      4:'d',
      5:'e'}


for left, right in pl.items():
   for values in right.values():
      print(values['Letters'])
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "plist.py", line 34, in <module>
    print(values['Letters'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

My goal is to return:
qrst
lmn

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access an inner dictionary key, you don't need to iterate. You can use `dict.__getitem__` or `dict.get`. But since your outer dictionary values aren't *all* dictionaries, you will need to either do some type-checking or use `try` / `except`.

Here's an example of the latter method:

```
for left, right in pl.items():
    try:
        print(right['Letters'])
    except TypeError:
        pass

qrst
lmn
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for k,v in pl.items():
   if type(v)==dict:
      print(v["Letters"])
   else:
      continue
```

Comment: all the best. Keep Posting more challenging questions. Happy Learning